# Separating one group from other samples where the other samples may not belong to the same population

Tags: clustering

The way I see it, this is somewhat of a modified clustering problem.

Let's say I have 1000 samples where the majority all follow the same behavior since they are from the same population. A number of these should stand out because they come from different populations. However, the ones that stand out aren't necessarily similar to one another.

If the ones that stood out did exhibit similar properties, I could probably do k = 2 means clustering and go from there. As it currently stands, I'm unsure how to proceed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds to me that you're describing outlier detection.

Answer (score 0):

The [one-class SVM](http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/) was designed for just this situation. Basically, instead of trying to separate your two classes from each other with a hyperplane, it tries to find the hyperplane that separates your data set from the origin, while being as far away from the origin as possible. In kernel space, this essentially corresponds to finding the smallest possible blob that contains your data (without overfitting). It's pretty cool.

That said, if you have enough of these outliers, you should also try just training standard classifiers on the problem (e.g. random forests or gradient boosting machines). The less-parametric classifiers can sometimes do quite well even when one class doesn't have that much in common--it really depends on the dataset.

Comment: I don't have class labels. I just know that the majority of the data is of one 'class', while the rest isn't. Can I still use supervised techniques?

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear from your question that you didn't have labels. Sorry. The wiki page on [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) may have some good resources, e.g. the [local outlier factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor) method or [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).